# UWP How to specify width height of Toast notification

Tags: c#, uwp, toast

Is there any way to control the height or width of toast notification. We have option to set images, buttons with images but is there any way to specify the width or height of any control (button, text, image)?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but how do you have that many points and think this is how to ask a question?  Please update the question to include example code.

Answer (score 0):

> UWP How to specify width height of Toast notification

We could not specify width height of toast, and each toast control has fixed size. The purpose of this is to make the toast look more consistent. Certainly, you could you design the different toast layout base your scenario. And you could use this [tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/notifications-visualizer/9nblggh5xsl1?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) to create toast quickly. Please refer this  official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts).

Answer (score 0):

A **Toast Notification** is a message that application **UWP** can display for the user , 
with well-defined restrictions and this in order to keep the same **UI/UX** experience of windows with a Restricted Template .

Toast Notification UX Guidance
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-ux-guidance